# "Cannot find variable charAt()" error in Java

Tags: java

I am getting the following error while running my simple Java program. This will lead me to make a bigger module.

**Error**

```
C:\Java prog>javac Testt.java
Testt.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable charAt
location: class java.lang.String
kk=k.charAt[i];
    ^
```

**The program**

```
class Testt
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String k="my name is bhola ram";
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(k.charAt[i]);
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
System.out.println(k.charAt(i));
```

the difference is that you're using array subscripts [] rather than the parantheses required for a function call. (thanks Andy)

[doc for charAt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)

Comment: +1: I also suggest you try an IDE as it should auto-complete this for you.

Comment: @Gautum, to be explicit, the difference is that you're using array subscripts [] rather than the parantheses required for a function call.

Comment: @Andy ill add that to the answer

Answer (score 0):

charAt() is a method of the String class.

methods take *parameters* not *indices*.

The first ones are given between ( and ).

The second ones are given between [ and ], and are often used for indicating the position in an array.

The mistake is made, I suspect, because in many programming languages a String *is* a kind of Array of chars that can take parameters.

So `MyString[2]` would be valid. This is not the case in Java however, hence the charAt(). method.